# How to override default behaviour of NavigationView and NavigationStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-animation

I'm curious, is there a way to override the default slide-in behaviour when navigating in SwiftUI? Here's some code where I'm unsuccessfully attempting to use `.transition` to affect the animation:

```swift
struct TransitionOnNavigation: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Press Me") {
                Text("Hello World!")
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom)) // this doesn't do anything
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm surprised that I haven't found anything in my searches for something so fundamental, and I don't recall seeing anything about this in WWDC videos. I *did* find [this library](https://github.com/davdroman/swiftui-navigation-transitions/blob/main/README.md), but I wonder if there's something built-in that I'm missing.

Ideally, I'd want to:

1. Change the basic type of transition (move, scale, fade, etc)
2. Affect the rate of animation (eg using `duration` parameters)
3. Have the ability to use matchedGeometryEffect control individual views in interesting ways.

Answer (score 1):

As per I know SwiftUI natively supports custom transition between Views when using `NavigationStack` / `NavigationSplitView`.
You can try with [NavigationTransition](https://github.com/davdroman/swiftui-navigation-transitions) which supports NavigationStack on iOS 16.

Add package to you project and import

```
import NavigationTransitions
```

Then

```
NavigationStack {
    // your content
}
.navigationTransition(.fade(.cross))
```

You can also combine predefined transitions or make a custom one.

Comment: Yes, that is using the library I linked to in the question. So it looks like there's no built-in way of doing this easily using only Apple's APIs.